# Javascript Math.floor issue between specific range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, floating-point-precision

I'm facing an issue with Math.floor function of javascript for the below scenario:

1) from the value betwwen 8192 and 10484,

```
    if I type 8192.8  -> The Math.floor converts it into 8192.79

    if I type 8192.88  -> The Math.floor converts it into 8192.87

    if I type 8192.3  -> The Math.floor converts it into 8192.29
```

Strange part is that except from the range given above the function works fine.

```
HTML:
<div data-bind="text: popIncrease"></div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: userInput,  valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

Javascript:

var ViewModel = function () {
var _self = this;
_self.userInput = ko.observable();
_self.popIncrease = ko.computed(function () {

        return parseFloat((Math.floor(_self.userInput() * 100) / 100)).toFixed(2);
});
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/91z5bdy4/1/

When I changed 100 with 1000 it solved the error but I do not understand why this happened on the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Actually has nothing to do with knockout or jquery. What are you actually trying to do? It seem like you want to round a number to 2 decimal places then display it with 2 decimal places. Passing a number to *parseFloat* is redundant (it's already a number). An expression shouldn't be wrapped in double brackets like `((…))`, one set is redundant. Why not `return parseFloat(_self.userInput()).toFixed(2)`?

Comment: 8192.8 * 100 === 819279.9999999999, good luck with floating point arithmetics.

Comment: See [*How do I format a Number as a String with exactly 2 decimal places?*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#formatNumber).

Answer (score 1):

You can just switch to this:

```
return parseFloat(_self.userInput()).toFixed(2);
```

Working version of your jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5rLL04Lk/

---

Or, if you want to work around some of the idiosyncrasies of `.toFixed()`, you can use this:

```
return (Math.round(_self.userInput() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xx2aj2L0/

This solution passes all three of your test cases.

Comment: Except that the rounding in *toFixed* is buggy… `(3.335).toFixed(2)` gives '3.33' where '3.34' might be expected.

Comment: @RobG - offered another solution that works around that `.toFixed(2)` weirdness.

Comment: Of course there's still the ancient bug in IE's implementation of *toFixed* (jScript 5.8), but perhaps it's fixed now. ;-)

Comment: `8192.809` converts to `8192.81`, is that the desired result, or is supposed to be `8192.80`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not `Math.floor()` that causes the problem, it is the inexactness of the floating point arithmetic. When you multiply `8192.8` by `100`, you get `819279.9999999999`.

Perhaps you should just manipulate it as a string:

```
function floorString(str) {
    var pos = str.indexOf('.');
    return (pos >= 0) ? ((str + '00').slice(0, pos + 3)) : (str + '.00');
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn2pxp04/)

Comment: And rounding happens…?

Comment: @RobG - Am I misinterpreting the question? It looks like the OP is just truncating the number, not rounding.

Comment: No, I am. :-) I was assuming that the OP was trying to round the number, not just truncate it at 2 places.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your floor/parse seems out of order to me.

Try:

```
return Math.floor(parseFloat(_self.userInput())).toFixed(2);
```

Though be aware that 1.999999999999999999999999999999 gives 2.00 using the above; this is because floating point numbers aren't able to represent all values precisely.

Comment: 1.999999999 gives 2.00 because `.toFixed(2)` rounds to two decimal places.  There are issues with floating point precision, but your example is not where that comes into play.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's probably more to do with `parseFloat("1.9999999999999999999999999") === 2` being `true`.

Comment: @Paul—and `(1.999).toFixed(2) === '2.00'`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG While that's true, the Math.floor(1.999) in the code above would result in 1 being passed to .toFixed, resulting in 1.00 - yes?

Comment: @Paul—Yes. [SO limit].

Answer (score 0):

another one without using a `Math` function (2 lines without formatting)

```
function floorString(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/([\d]+(\.[\d]{0,2}))/);
    return matches === null || matches[2].length === 1 ?
            (str + ".00").replace("..", ".") :
            matches[2].length < 3 ?
                matches[0] + "00".substr(3 - matches[2].length) :
                matches[0];
}
```